# Internet Explorer 11 Create auto-response to closing MsgBox from specific website

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, internet-explorer-11

**Disclaimer:** the only language I have any proficiency with at all is VBA. I know next to nothing about html and zero about javascript. That said, I think what I'm looking to do is pretty simple, also:

I currently use IE for only one website. The site performs well with IE, but has an annoying closing message box I'd like to bypass. The message has only one option—"Okay"—so from my POV is pretty pointless. Is it possible to create a routine within my instance of IE that will automatically OK this message so that closing is a one-step process instead of two steps?

Comment: Try to use Application.sendkeys to simulate Enter keypress that can help to close that popup. You can try to test it with your code and let us know about your testing result.

Comment: Are you trying to automatically press the Ok button whenever it appears?  I'm assuming this is not your website but one you are visiting?

Comment: Deepak-MSFT, JDesuv Thank you both. Yes, it's a site I visit. And I thought sendkeys might be the clue. But the thing is, I'm so green with this. I don't even know where you write the code. There's no developer window the way there is with Office products. Can you point me in the right direction to give this a shot? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing the site manually then there is no place to use Application.sendkeys.

If you are using VBA code to automate the site then I noticed that VBA code gets paused while msgbox gets displayed. In that case, Application.sendkeys line will not get execute and popup will not get closed using code. So if you are using VBA code then there is a possibility you can meet with this issue.

To overcome this issue, you can try to use the [Selenium web driver](https://www.selenium.dev/projects/) to automate IE.  There is a proper way to handle a msg box.

Example:

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

References:

1. [Alert & Popup Window Handling in Selenium WebDriver](https://www.guru99.com/alert-popup-handling-selenium.html)
2. [How to handle Alerts and Pop-ups in Selenium](https://www.edureka.co/blog/alerts-popups-in-selenium)
3. [WORKING WITH JAVASCRIPT POPUP BOXES IN SELENIUM WEBDRIVER](http://pragmatictestlabs.com/2018/02/12/working-javascript-popup-boxes-selenium-webdriver/)

Let me know if something is unclear. I will try to provide further suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for these resources. I will have a look at them, and see what I can do. But please, one very basic question first: to use selenium, do I need to download a separate program, or is it an add-on, or do I start with a text document, or how is this done? 

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm grateful for what you've offered here. However I got as far as this, on the Selenium site— 
> _"... At a minimum you need a test framework that matches the language bindings, e.g. NUnit for .NET, JUnit for Java, RSpec for Ruby, etc. The test framework is responsible for running and executing your WebDriver and related steps in your tests..."_ <
and put the brakes on. It appears to be way too big a learning curve to tackle for the sake of avoiding one "Okay" click.

Comment: (continued) That said, this stuff is fascinating to me, and hope to return to it soon. Please do let me know if I'm making it more complicated than it seems, but otherwise it seems best to put it on hold. I've marked your answer as "helpful," but because I'm new here, I guess it doesn't show up.

Comment: If you can locate the calling code for that msgbox in the HTML page then you can try to remove it using VBA code. It can be a workaround for this issue.